# Customizing a WordPress Template to Remove *One* Page Title

Tags: php, wordpress, web, customization

I'm using WordPress to build a simple personal website. I know (basic) HTML and CSS but no PHP, so I'm having a little trouble with a particular customization.

My theme inserts the title of the page at the top of the page. I would like to stop it from doing this on one page only (the home page).

[image]

Thanks for any help. The site is here: http://www.melvingauci.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try going into your page.php template and remove `<?php the_title(); ?>`. Then add this:

```
<?php if ( ! is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**Note:** This assumes your home page uses the page.php template. If another template is used, then the same approach will work.